# Replacing a SQL Server subquery in a stored procedure with a string variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exec, temp-tables

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateAsset 
    @NumeratorQuery AS TEXT,
    @DenominatorQuery AS TEXT,
    @family AS VARCHAR(255),
    @control_num AS VARCHAR(255),
    @metric_sequence AS VARCHAR(255)
AS
    -- Drop Temporary Tables if they exist
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempNumerator') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#TempNumerator

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempDenominator') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#TempDenominator

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempAssets') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#TempAssets

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempSummary') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#TempSummary

    -- Create Temporary Numerator Table
    SELECT * 
    INTO #TempNumerator 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT AssetID 
         FROM openquery(RISKFABRIC_SACS_PROD, 'SELECT computer_name AS AssetID
                                               FROM SACS_PROD.assets 
                                               WHERE (device_type = "SERVER" OR 
                                                      device_type = "INDETERMINATE" OR 
                                                      device_type = "VIRTUAL MACHINE") 
                                                 AND (status = "ACTIVE (PER DOCUMENTATION)" OR status="ACTIVE (DEFINITIVE)")')
            ) AS #TempNumerator
.
.
.
```

In the above stored procedure, I want to replace everything inside the subquery with `@NumeratorQuery` like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TempNumerator 
FROM (@NumeratorQuery) AS #TempNumerator
```

How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it will look like this:

```
Create Table #TempNumerator
(
    field list...
)

insert into #TempNumerator
exec (@NumeratorQuery)
```

Comment: This is about what I thought, except that I'm using SELECT INTO. The problem is that I get a syntax error near the EXEC. i.e. I just put exec (@NumeratorQuery) to replace the xxxxx... but it gave syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE@NumeratorQuery NVARCHAR(500)
    SET@NumeratorQuery ='SELECT DISTINCT AssetID
    FROM openquery(RISKFABRIC_SACS_PROD,'SELECT computer_name AS AssetID
    FROM SACS_PROD.assets
    WHERE(device_type="SERVER"OR
    device_type="INDETERMINATE"OR
    device_type="VIRTUAL MACHINE")
    AND(status="ACTIVE (PER DOCUMENTATION)"OR status="ACTIVE (DEFINITIVE)")'

    EXEC(@NumeratorQuery)
```

Comment: I think that this is what I would use outside my stored procedure, though nesting of quotes needs a fixin. and then I would pipe that variable along with 5 others to my stored procedure... then your exec line would be in that stored procedure and not ourside it... the exec line is the issue, it causes a syntax error I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

I found the real root cause of the problem. Putting EXEC in the FROM clause of a SELECT INTO statement is not supported in older versions of MSSQL, but it is supported in newer versions I've read.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TempNumerator 
FROM EXEC(@NumeratorQuery) AS #TempNumerator
```

That's really the root cause; the same restriction is not present for the insert statement so thus, this works perfectly:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempNumerator (AssetID VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #TempNumerator EXEC(@NumeratorQuery)
```